# Calculate the integral of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ of the field $[P,Q]^T=[x^2+y^2,x^2-y]^T$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

Calculate the integral of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ of the field $[P,Q]^T=[x^2+y^2,x^2-y]^T$.

I can't find solution of this problem. I'll be greatfull for answer. Thanks.

Comment: It is not allowed to ask for a solution of homework here. You should demonstrate your own work and only in case your ideas don't work (which has to be demonstrated in the question) you should ask for an advice.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) will help asking a good question...

Answer (score 0):

These are my calculations:

$x^2+y^2=1$, $R=1,  S[0,0]$

$P = x^2+y$

$Q = x^2-y$

$\frac{(\omega)Q}{dx}=2x$,  $\frac{(\omega)P}{dy}=1$

$\oint_T Pdx +Qdy=\iint_T(\frac{(\omega)Q}{dx}-\frac{(\omega)P}{dy})dxdy$

$\oint_T x^2+ydx+x^2-ydy=\iint_T (2x-1)dxdy$

$x=Rcos\phi$,  $y=Rsin\phi$

$0\le R \le 1$

$0\le \phi \le 2\pi$

$dxdy=RdRd\phi$

$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}(2Rcos\phi-1)dR\phi dR$

$\int_0^1 [2Rsin \phi - \phi]_0^{2 \pi}RdR=\int_0^1(2Rsin2 \pi - 2\pi-2Rsin0)RdR=$

$=\int_0^1(-2\pi) RdR=-2\pi \int_0^1RdR=-2\pi [\frac 12R^2]_0^2=$

$=-2 \pi * \frac 12=-\pi$

It took me a while but finally I came to the result. I'm not sure if it's correct but maybe it will help someone.